# REST Api -API response doesn't have a consistent default content type in header

Tags: java, web-services, rest, api

**When i make the request from rest-easy using below URL and  code.I am getting different responses for each request(Call the  API without specifying content type in the request headers. Do this multiple times to see the  different results).I am using rest-easy(Firefox plug-in) to invoke the URL and get response**

I would like to get the response in "text/plain" by default. There are other formats too like java/x-java-properties, text/xml.
If I do not specify the Accept parameter in the request header, i would like to get the text/plain response. Now i get text/plain sometimes and sometimes text/x-java-properties or text/xml

The deployed version is in my local system.I am able to get the response y invoking the following URL:

**Url:http://localhost:8081/restfuljersey/rest/hello**

code:

```
import javax.ws.rs.GET; 
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
@Path("/hello")
public class Hello {
  @GET
  @Produces("text/plain")
  public String sayPlainTextHello() {
    return "Hello Jersey Plain";
  }
  @GET
  @Produces("text/x-java-properties")
  public String sayHtmlHelloProperties( ) {
          return "Hello Jersey Plain1111";
  }
  // This method is called if XML is request
  @GET
  @Produces("text/xml")
  public String sayXMLHello() {
    return "<?xml version=\"1.0\"?>" + "<hello> Hello Jersey" + "</hello>";
  }
  // This method is called if HTML is request
  @GET
  @Produces("text/html")
  public String sayHtmlHello() {
    return "<html> " + "<title>" + "Hello Jersey" + "</title>"
        + "<body><h1>" + "Hello Jersey HTML" + "</h1></body>" + "</html> ";
  }
}
```

Comment: What is the current response? What you want to achieve?

Comment: I would like to get the response in "text/plain" by default.But I am getting different response like text/plain or text/x-java-properties or text/xml  for each request.

Answer (score 0):

All browsers use a set of default values for the Accept header in an HTTP request unless you specify the header yourself.

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Content_negotiation/List_of_default_Accept_values

E.g. firefox uses `Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8`

Among those values you find the wildcard header `*/*` which allows the server to choose the content type it returns. Browsers use it to cover all possible cases.

Comment: how does the server identify the response type if it is /*/*? Any default to be specified? any configurations to be done?

Comment: @Seshadri this depends on the JAX-RS implementation of the server. You can't assume that all servers return the same content type on receipt of the `Accept: */*` header, e.g. the Jersey framework could return a totally different content type than the RESTEasy framework. I'm not aware of a way to configure this behavior.